# Proposed tag synonym: pension + retirement-funds

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I propose to make these tags synonyms:

- [pension](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pension)
- [retirement-funds](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retirement-funds)

Comment: Which one do we want to keep?

Answer (score 1):

Agreed. Wealth on this site should be mostly about context - not about how you came into collecting it. In that sense, there's no difference between a pension you get from your company and an annuity that pays you periodic lump sums.

Which one do we want to keep?

Comment: I *vote* for [tag:pension]

Comment: I vote for [tag:retirement-funds]. I don't think of an [IRA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_IRA) as being a [pension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pension), but I think of both as being retirement funds.

Comment: Not all pension schemes are funds, retirement-funds is too specific.